# How to evaluate a when condition for Ansible task

Tags: regex, ansible

I am having a variable with the following value:

```
   name_prefix: stage-dbs
```

I am having a task in my playbook which will have to check this variable and see if it contains *-dbs , if the condition is met then it should process. I wrote something like this :

```
- name: Ensure deployment directory is present
  file:
    path=/var/tmp/deploy/paTestTool
    state=directory
  when: name_prefix =="*-dbs" # what condition is required here to evaulate the rest part of variable??
```

What regex pattern should be used or how to use a regex here ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need to use regex for pattern searching. You can use search like this:

```
when: name_prefix | search("stage-dbs")
```

It will definitely work.

Comment: This avoids the fact that a regex is sometimes very useful - eg:  "[Jj]ava *[Kk]ey[Ss]tore" not in cmd.stdout is safer than assuming spacing and capitalization is consistent.   So "no need to use regex" is missing the point, (as well as an indefinite article) IMO.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls `search("stage-dbs")` should probably be `regex_search("*-dbs")` in the answer.

Comment: @ws_e_c421: Actually, I believe that your regex has an error:  "\*-dbs" means 0 or more of nothing followed by "-dbs".  I suspect that you mean (".*-dbs"), where the leading "." means any single character.

Comment: @ws_e_c421 - sorry if I was overly pedantic!

Comment: @GrahamNicholls No problem. I was just acknowledging you are right. If I could have, I would have just edited the comment. My main intent was point out the existence of `regex_search` since the answer could have used it instead of `search` and then more directly addressed the original question like you pointed out.

Comment: using regex_serch with a single quote and no need for *

Comment: had err: "no filter named 'search'" - needed to be "... in search" rather than "... | search" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787529/getting-an-while-executing-a-ansible-playbook-using-when-module

Answer (score 18):

Not sure filter `search` exists today?

solution with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions :

```
when: name_prefix | regex_search("^stage-dbs(.*)$")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "|" is depreciated in ansible 2.9.* .Instead of using
`name_prefix |search` use `name_prefix is search`. This feature will be removed in version 2.9