# Getting an while executing a ansible playbook using when module

Tags: ansible

Am trying to execute playbook with when module

```yaml
when: rxbar.stdout | join ('') | search("foo: ") and ansible_distribution_major_version|int >= 7
```

Am getting an error:.

> Template error while templating string: no filter named 'search'. String rxbar.stdout

Comment: As said in the error, there is no Jinja filter, nor is there an Ansible extension to Jinja offering a `search` filter.

Comment: I guess what you are looking at is `when: "'foo: ' in rxbar.stdout and ansible_distribution_major_version|int >= 7"`, but without any information of what you have as input and what you want as output, this is not really something we can answer. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is self explanatory.

```
Template error while templating string: no filter named 'search'. String rxbar.stdout
```

search is not a filter you are using here.

Example for search in when

```
 - debug:
            msg: "matched pattern 2"
          when: url is search("/users/.*/resources/.*")
```

search succeeds if it finds the pattern anywhere within string.